# How to use link_to_function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I am using statement:

```
`$`.link_to_function "Greeting", "alert('Hello world!')", :class => "nav_link"
```

It's working fine.

But If

```
`$`.link_to_function "Greeting", "my_function", :class => "nav_link"
```

I have defined my_function in application.js

```
`$`.function my_function(){
    alert("my function called");
}
```

I am using rails 3.2.1

Thanks in advance,
Ashish

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript function calls must always include parenthesis, even if they have no arguments. So try this:

```
`$`.link_to_function "Greeting", "my_function()", :class => "nav_link"
```

Comment: In view I have code as `<%= link_to_function("Click Me","click_me()",html_options={:id => "click"}) %>`. In js i Have code `$(document).ready(function(){
        function click_me(){
                alert("I am called");
        }
});`  It's not working for me

Comment: But if js code is like `$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#click").click(click_me);
        function click_me(){
                alert("I am called");
        }
});` then it's working. Can I call function click_me without click function?

Comment: Sorry I got solution I have modified my js file. Now it's like `function click_me(){
                alert("I am called");
}` and it's working for me now